# Django isn't loading static admin files

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

when I access to my admin dashboard in Django, it doesn't load css and img files, so doesn't work well.
All the files are in 'project/static/admin', and in my settins.py I have this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

When I execute collectstatic, appears: `0 static files copied to '/opt/myenv/myenv/static', 318 unmodified.`

I'm using Nginx + Gunicorn, also I'm using https with Cloudflare.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: did you set `location /static {
    root /path/static/;
}` in your nginx file

Comment: I just posted an answer about, @Alasdair is right, you should put `STATICFILES_DIRS`

Answer (score 1):

You run `collectstatic` with `STATIC_ROOT` set up
If you do not have this in your `settings.py` , add it

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

Comment: The OP already has `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")`. The `STATIC_ROOT` should not appear in `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Comment: I remember that I had the same problem, it was with AWS, in my settings.py, I didn't have STATIC_ROOT, only STATICFILES_DIRS, and it worked

Comment: You don't need `STATIC_ROOT` while you are running with `DEBUG=True` in development, but you do need to set it before you can run `collectstatic` in production.